# Do I need JWTs with Passport.js?

Tags: express, jwt, passport.js

I have been using Auth0 to create user accounts on my react webpage. It uses JWTs, sent to the server, to authenticate and protect the routes.

I am now working on a express based app that uses Auth0 and Passport.js. The server uses a middleware function and calls the .isAuthenticated() function, checking to see if the user is logged in. My client is asking if I should 'upgrade' this system to use JWTs instead of using this middleware. Would ya'll be able to guide me? Should I try to change his website to use JWTs?

Thanks!

Here is the middleware function for all the routes -

```
const isLoggedIn = (request, response, next) => {
// if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
if (request.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
// if they aren't, redirect them to the home page
response.redirect('/login');
};
```

I found the method in the passport files - Now I guess I need to figure out what _passport is in order to see if its secure.

```
/**
* Test if request is authenticated.
*
* @return {Boolean}
* @api public
*/
  req.isAuthenticated = function() {
    var property = 'user';
    if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {
      property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';
    }

 return (this[property]) ? true : false;
```

};

Comment: what does the isAuthenticated method do?

Comment: Check the isAuthenticated method as mentioned by @Sandor . Maybe the system is already using JWT. JWT and middleware is two separate thing. Even if you use JWT, you will still have this middleware (or any similar middleware) to decode the JWT to check the payload and validate the correctness of the token & finally confirm the authentication.

Comment: I have no idea. I found the method but I am at a loss to know if my routes are secure/ if I should try to use JWT instead. I posted the method above, but I dont think it will help me figure this out yet.